# How to export actions generated from extraReducers and createAsyncThunk

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I am trying to write my first async thunk with the provided function from Redux Toolkit: `createAsyncThunk`.

But after hours reading the docs and online instructions, it seems I am missing something as I can't import the action `rollDice`.

`GenerateRandomDice.spec.ts`

```
import { beforeEach, describe, expect, it } from 'vitest'
import { ReduxStore } from '../../../react-view/main'
import { configureStoreWith } from '../../../app/store'
import { Dependencies } from '../../../app/dependencies'
import { InMemoryIdProvider } from '../../../infrastructure/idProvider/InMemoryIdProvider'
import { InMemoryRandomDiceProvider } from '../../../infrastructure/randomDiceProvider/InMemoryRandomDiceProvider'

describe('Generate Random Dice', () => {
  let store: ReduxStore
  let dependencies: Dependencies

  beforeEach(() => {
    dependencies = {
      idProvider: new InMemoryIdProvider(),
      randomDiceProvider: new InMemoryRandomDiceProvider(),
    }
    store = configureStoreWith(dependencies)
  })

  it('should generate 10 random dice', () => {
    store.dispatch(rollDice())
    const state = store.getState()

    expect(state).toBe('something') // I don't expect this to pass, it's not the point
  })
})
```

`diceSlice.ts`

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { Dependencies } from '../../app/dependencies'

type ExtraDependencies = {
  extra: Dependencies
}

const rollDice = createAsyncThunk<number, any, ExtraDependencies>(
  `dice/rollDice`,
  async (thunkAPI, { extra: { randomDiceProvider } }) => {
    return randomDiceProvider.generateRandomDieValue()
  },
)

export const initialState = {
  dice: [] as number[],
  loading: false,
  error: null,
}

export const diceSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'dice',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(rollDice.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.dice.push(action.payload)
    })
  },
})

export const diceReducer = diceSlice.reducer
```

As far as I understand it, the `createSlice` functions should somehow create the action for me, but it's not the case.

[image: Webstorm screenshot]

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you put this example into codesandbox? that will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found the issue with the help of a forum, so I am posting here for reference.

So first I needed to `export` the `rollDice` generated by `createAsyncThunk`.

That has triggered a first error: `createAsyncThunk.d.ts(108, 118): An argument for 'arg' was not provided.` So I needed to change the `ThunkArg` type from `any` to `void`.

Second, I had a big no overlap that was resolve by digging in `configureStoreWith`.

```
import {
  combineReducers,
  configureStore,
  ThunkMiddleware,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { diceSlice } from '../core/dice/diceSlice'
import { Dependencies } from './dependencies'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  dice: diceSlice.reducer,
})

export const configureStoreWith = (dependencies: Partial<Dependencies>) =>
  configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware({
        serializableCheck: false,
        thunk: {
          extraArgument: dependencies,
        },
      }),
  })
```

I had to remove the `Partial` to make it work. I'd like to keep it partial so as not to have to instantiate all my dependencies for all the tests, but instead "cherry-instanciate" for the need of the test only.

I am not sure how I could achieve that though.